# bypass the exit code in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh

So I have a little script that is supposed to SSH into a 1000 or so accounts over different servers, as below.

```
for account in $(cat $SSH_LIST)
  do echo -e "\n$account\n"
  SERVER=$(echo $account | cut -d',' -f1 | awk '{print tolower($0)}') ; USER=$(echo $account | cut -d',' -f2) ; PASS=$(echo $account | cut -d',' -f3)
  sshpass -p $PASS ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $USER@$SERVER "ls passwd.cdb && exit"
```

Problem is, the moment that ssh hits a permission denied, the script exits. Understandably, the SSH Permission Denied acts like an exit code and exits out the script. I need it to simply log the denied permission and continue on its merry way SSH'ing.

Any advice?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Normally, bash would not exit on the first error, unless `set -e` is set higher up in your script. Try putting this before your `for` loop.

```
set +e
```

*p.s. You're missing a `done` at the end of your loop. I assume that's just a cut and paste error.*

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
if ! sshpass -p $PASS ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $USER@$SERVER "ls passwd.cdb && exit"; then
    echo >&2 "WARNING: access denied for $USER@$SERVER"
fi
```

Also you can use logical operators `OR`:

```
sshpass -p $PASS ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $USER@$SERVER "ls passwd.cdb && exit" ||
    echo >&2 "WARNING: access denied for $USER@$SERVER"
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to update here, I know it's been a while, been busy :). turns out set -e was set in some obfuscated code in the top of the script. had the guy who obfuscated the code remove it. Also thanks to slava semushin for the nice idea to log access denied messages.